# Do you need to install a gem for each separate rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Like the title says, if I use a gem in one app (install it, add to Gemfile, etc.) do I still have to run `gem install xxx` in a new app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're not using Bundler, you very rarely need to run `gem install ...` at all, actually.

More often than not, unless you're using different Rubies for each of your projects, all of your gems live in folders that get shared across all of the projects that use them. If you're using `rvm` you can see this directory by running `rvm gemdir`.

When you use Bundler, it will automatically handle loading the appropriate version of the gem in the (likely) case that you have several versions installed.

Answer (score 2):

No.

In fact, for a modern (Rails 3+) app you should never need to run `gem install` (except, of course, for the initial `gem install bundler rails` that you need to do once), you should just add the gem to your Gemfile and then run `bundle install`. Let Bundler take care of dependencies and installing for you, that's what it's there for.